# Redireccionar a otra pagina en boton Aceptar y emitir documento PDF

Tags: php, html

Tengo esta situacion:

1.- Registro mis datos y al momento de dar click en Aceptar; se guardan registros y se crea un documento en PDF con FPDF sin ningun problema

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="text-center">
      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="this.disabled=true; this.value=’Enviando...’; this.form.submit()" id="btn-registrar">Aceptar</button>                       
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-cancelar">Cancelar</button>
         <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("btn-cancelar").onclick = function () {
            location.href = "../menu.php";
            };
         </script>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
   </div>
</div>
</form>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al dar click en aceptar se manda por POST a el archivo `guarda.view.php` el cual contiene este código:

```
    <?php session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

  require('verificar.view.php');


   echo'<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("DATOS ACTUALIZADOS GRACIAS");     
    window.location="../menu.php"
    </script>';

    } else {
  header('Location: ../index.php');
}

 ?>
```

2.- Dentro de este código se manda a traer el PDF con la información que llené en el formulario sin ningún problema.

Necesito que: al momento de que guarda el PDF se me redireccione a la URL `../menu.php` pero el código no lo hace. Es decir, me genera el PDF, se guarda en el equipo pero no se redirecciona y se queda en el formulario donde estaba llenando los datos.

Aqui dejo un fragmento del inicio y final del código para mostrar el PDF.

```
<?php session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

$modelo=$_POST['modelo'];
$serie=$_POST['serie'];
$testigo1=$_POST['testigo1'];
$fecha_alta=$_SESSION['fecha_alta'];
$email_administrativo=$_SESSION['email_administrativo'];
$email_usuario=$_POST['email_usuario'];
$fecha1="Estando de acuerdo en lo antes señalado, firman como responsables en la ciudad de ".$_SESSION['ciudad']." el dia ".$_SESSION['fecha']."";

$config['db']=array(
         'host'=> 'localhost',
         'username'=>'root',
         'password'=>'*****',
         'dbname'=>'database'
         );

         $db=new PDO('mysql:host='.$config['db']['host'].';dbname='.$config['db']['dbname'],$config['db']['username'],$config['db']['password']);
         $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   

         try{/*AQUI VA TODO EL CUERPO DEL PDF/*

         catch(PDOException $e)
         {

         echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
         }      
         $db = null; 

} else {
  header('Location: ../index.php');
}
?>
```

Ahora bien. Agregue lo siguiente Este archivo guarda el registro.

```
    <?php session_start();
   if(isset($_POST["aceptar"]) && $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) { 

         header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

$modelo=$_POST['modelo'];
$serie=$_POST['serie'];
$testigo1=$_POST['testigo1'];
$fecha_alta=$_SESSION['fecha_alta'];
$email_administrativo=$_SESSION['email_administrativo'];
$email_usuario=$_POST['email_usuario'];
$fecha1="Estando de acuerdo en lo antes señalado, firman como responsables en la ciudad de ".$_SESSION['ciudad']." el dia ".$_SESSION['fecha']."";

$config['db']=array(
         'host'=> 'localhost',
         'username'=>'root',
         'password'=>'*****',
         'dbname'=>'database'
         );

       $db=new PDO('mysql:host='.$config['db']['host'].';dbname='.$config['db']['dbname'],$config['db']['username'],$config['db']['password']);
         $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   

         try{

         $sql="INSERT INTO `custodia_equipo_electronico`(
       `fecha_alta`,
       `numero_empleado`,
       `nombre_completo`,
       `empresa`,
       `apoderado_legal`,
       `modelo`,
       `serie`,
       `centro_laboral`,      
       `gerente_administrativo`,
       `testigo1`,
       `fecha_expedicion`,
       `email_administrativo`,
       `email_usuario`)
       VALUES
         (STR_TO_DATE('$fecha_alta', '%d/%m/%Y'),
       '{$_SESSION[numero]}',
       '{$_SESSION['nombre_completo']}',
       '{$_SESSION['empresa']}',
       '{$_SESSION['Apoderado_Legal']}',
       '$modelo',
       '$serie',
       '{$_SESSION['centro_laboral']}',
       '{$_SESSION['gerente_administrativo']}',
       '$testigo1',     
       '$fecha1',
       '$email_administrativo',
       '$email_usuario')";
       $db->exec("SET NAMES'utf8'");
       $db->exec($sql);
       $last_id = $db->lastInsertId(); 
       }   
       catch(PDOException $e)
         {      
         echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
         }     

       //$db = null; 
       //$sql = null; 
       //$sql1 = null; 
       //$conexion = null; 


         ?>
<html lang="es">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Resultado</title>
      <link href="../libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/form-elements.css" type="text/css" />
      <script src="../libs/js/Respond/src/respond.js"></script>
      <script src="../libs/js/Respond/src/matchmedia.addListener.js"></script>
      <script src="../libs/js/Respond/src/matchmedia.polyfill.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="inner-bg">
            <div class="container">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text">
                     <div class="text-center">
                        <img title="logo" src="../images/logogruver.png">                        
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="container">
                  <?php
                     echo "<script>alert('Custodia Registrada.');</script>"; 
                     echo "".$last_id."";
                        //require('verificar.view.php');
                        //header('Location: ../menu.php');
                     ?>
                  <br>
                  <br>
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="text-center">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                           <p>Regresar al Menú Principal:
                              <a href="../menu.php" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Menú 
                              </a>
                           </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                           <p>Descargar PDF:
                              <a href="verificar.view.php" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="imprime">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span> Descargar
                              </a>
                              <script>
                              $(function () {
                                 $('#imprime').on('click', function () {
                                    var last_id = $(this).data().last_id;
                                    $.post( 'verifica.view.php', { last_id: last_id } );
                                    });
                                });

                              </script>
                           </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                           <p>Salir del Sistema:
                              <a href="../ldap/cerrar-sesion.php" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Salir 
                              </a>
                           </p>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
<?php
   } 
   else {   header('Location: ../index.php');   }
   }

   ?>
```

Y en el boton que dice "Descargar PDF:" necesito se genere el PDF y este es el codigo para generar el PDF

```
    <?php session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {      

         include('../conn/conexion_mb.php');

         $ultimo_registro=isset($_POST['last_id']);

         $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM custodia_equipo_electronico WHERE folio LIKE '$ultimo_re' ORDER BY folio ASC";
         mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8");
         $resultado = $conexion->query($sql1);
         if ($resultado->num_rows > 0)
         {
             while($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc())   {
             $folio=$fila['folio'];
             $fecha_alta=$fila['fecha_alta'];
             $numero_empleado=$fila['numero_empleado'];
             $nombre=$fila['nombre_completo'];
             $empresa=$fila['empresa'];
             $apoderado_legal=$fila['apoderado_legal'];
             $modelo=$fila['modelo'];
             $serie=$fila['serie'];
             $centro_laboral=$fila['centro_laboral'];
             $gerente_administrativo=$fila['gerente_administrativo'];
             $testigo1=$fila['testigo1'];
             $fecha_expedicion=$fila['fecha_expedicion'];   
             $email_administrativo=$fila['email_administrativo'];
             $email_usuario=$fila['email_usuario'];     }
         }
            else
         {
             echo'<script type="text/javascript">
             alert("NO EXISTEN DATOS EN LA BASE DE DATOS");
             window.location="../menu.php"
             </script>';
             exit;
         }

header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
include_once('../libs/fpdf/fpdf.php'); 
class PDF extends FPDF
{
    function Footer()
    {
        $this->SetY(-15);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Departamento de Sistemas','T',0,'C');
    }
    function Header()
    {

        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
        $this->Cell(50);        
        $this->Cell(100,10,utf8_decode('Formato Custodia Equipo Electrónico'),0,0,'C');
        $this->Cell(30,10,'',0,0,'C',$this->Image('../images/logogruver.png', 169,6, 32));
        $this->Ln(15);
    }   
}

$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage('P', 'Letter');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
$pdf->Cell(0,1,'Folio : '.$folio.'',0,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(50,5,'',0,1);
$pdf->MultiCell(195,5,utf8_decode("Por medio del presente instrumento, la empresa ".$_SESSION['empresa']." representada en este acto por C.P. ".$_SESSION['Apoderado_Legal']." en su carácter de apoderado legal, entrega el equipo  ".$modelo.", número de serie  ".$serie." al Sr.(a)  ".$_SESSION['nombre_completo']." actualmente laborando en la sucursal ".$_SESSION['centro_laboral'].".") ,0,'J',false);
$pdf->Cell (50,5,'',0,1);
$pdf->MultiCell(195,5,utf8_decode("El cual recibe a su entera satisfacción y en buenas condiciones de uso, obligándose a devolverlo en las mismas condiciones en que las que le fue asignado, considerando el deterioro normal y esperado del mismo, en el momento en que le sea requerido.") ,0,'J',false);
$pdf->Cell (50,5,'',0,1);
$pdf->MultiCell(195,5,utf8_decode("El equipo anteriormente descrito, es asignado como Herramienta de Trabajo en apoyo al desarrollo de sus actividades; su autorización se sustenta en la aprobación de la Dirección General de la empresa sujetándose a las siguientes condiciones:") ,0,'J',false);
$pdf->Cell (50,5,'',0,1);
$pdf->MultiCell(195,5,utf8_decode("1. El equipo se entrega al puesto, no a la persona, quedando en todo momento al servicio de la empresa.") ,0,'J',false);
$pdf->Cell (50,5,'',0,1);
$pdf->MultiCell(195,5,utf8_decode("2. El equipo estará asignado para el desarrollo del trabajo diario de su titular, debiendo pernoctar en la empresa en ausencias por vacaciones, permisos e incapacidades.
") ,0,'J',false);
$pdf->Cell (50,5,'',0,1);
$pdf->MultiCell(195,5,utf8_decode("3. El titular que ocupe el puesto, será el depositario, usuario y responsable único y total del bien recibido, quedando bajo su custodia la vigilancia y reporte oportuno de cualquier necesidad de mantenimiento.") ,0,'J',false);
$pdf->Cell (50,5,'',0,1);
$pdf->MultiCell(195,5,utf8_decode("4. En caso de robo, extravío o daños, que hagan imposible el uso óptimo del equipo y el titular responsable no pueda comprobar lo anterior o le sean imputables a él las causas, se cargarán a éste los daños y perjuicios causados a la empresa, aceptando y autorizando, desde este momento, se le realicen los descuentos en términos del artículo 110 de la Ley Federal de Trabajo.") ,0,'J',false);
$pdf->Cell (50,5,'',0,1);
$pdf->MultiCell(195,5,utf8_decode("5. Al momento en que el empleado se separe de la empresa, sea por la causa que fuere, se hará una valuación del estado actual del equipo, para que en caso de que por el mal uso del mismo éste se encontrara deteriorado, se le haga responsable de su demérito.
") ,0,'J',false);
$pdf->Cell (50,5,'',0,1);
$pdf->MultiCell(195,5,utf8_decode("6. El equipo se entrega configurado y listo para el uso del personal, con entendido de que podrá ser solicitado en el momento que se requiera para una revisión física e interna del mismo, y en caso de encontrar alteraciones o uso inadecuado se procederá con un acta administrativa o el retiro del equipo
") ,0,'J',false);
$pdf->Cell (50,5,'',0,1);
$pdf->MultiCell(195,5,utf8_decode(''.$fecha1.'') ,0,'J',false);
$pdf->Cell(50,5,'',0,1);
$pdf->Cell(50,5,'',0,1);
$pdf->Cell(100,5,'___________________________________',0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(100,5,'___________________________________',0,1,'C');
$pdf->Cell(100,5,utf8_decode(''.$_SESSION['nombre_completo'].''),0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(100,5,utf8_decode(''.$_SESSION['Apoderado_Legal'].''),0,1,'C');
$pdf->Cell(100,5,'',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(100,5,'',0,1);
$pdf->Cell(100,5,'Usuario Final',0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(100,5,'Apoderado Legal',0,1,'C');
$pdf->Cell(100,5,'',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(100,5,'',0,1);
$pdf->Cell(100,5,'___________________________________',0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(100,5,'___________________________________',0,1,'C');
$pdf->Cell(100,5,utf8_decode(''.$_SESSION['gerente_administrativo'].''),0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(100,5,utf8_decode(''.$testigo1.''),0,1,'C');
$pdf->Cell(100,5,'',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(100,5,'',0,1);
$pdf->Cell(100,5,'Gerente Administrativo',0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(100,5,'Testigo',0,1,'C');
$pdf->SetXY(10,210);
$pdf->Ln();


$pdfdoc=$pdf->Output('Custodia.pdf', 'D');//PARA DESCARGAR EN PC



} else {
  header('Location: ../index.php');
}
?>
```

La idea es que me genere el PDF y al momento de ejecutar me dice "No existen datos en la Base de Datos" siendo que si se registro y sigue activo el numero de registro hasta que cierro la ventana. Gracias.

Comment: Solo por curiosidad.

1. ¿Envias el formulario por AJAX?
2. ¿Por qué no usas header para redireccionar a menú?

Comment: No. Lo unico que mando por AJAX es la busqueda de los datos y posterior muestra algunas variables en el archivo del formulario, posterior al dar clic en Aceptar se guardarn con Insert en la BD, posterior se genera el PDF pero no es por AJAX. Ya utilice header y no tampoco me redirige, es mas, una vez que genera el PDF ahi para la ejecucion.

Comment: *"una vez que genera el PDF ahi para la ejecucion"*. Definitivamente eso no es normal. Te recomiendo agregues el código en donde generas el PDF.

Comment: ¿Alguna observación mas? ¿Alguna otra opinión? Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Si el problema es la descarga de archivo entonces porque mejor no controlar la descarga.*

Cuando uno quería descargar un archivo pero no quería la típico descarga de un archivo uno tenía que hacer un truco, jugar con `HTML Iframes`, donde dinámica lo generabas le aplicabas algunos estilos y le asignabas una ruta para que pueda descargar de forma *backgroung* un archivo. Pero cual era el problema, que no podías detectar si existió un error con la descarga como contralar el mensaje de `descargando...`. Entonces encontré una alternativa que me simplificaba el problema. [**jQuery File Download Plugin for Ajax**](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/)

---

**Solución a tu problema:** Directo al código, solo adecué a lo que necesitas.

Hice 3 archivos:

- formulario1.php: Que tendrá el ejemplo de utilizar el plugin de descarga.
- devolverArchivo.php: Para el ejemplo que planteo solo descarga una imagen, en tu caso lo adecuas para un archivo PDF.
- formulario2.php: No tienen nada de contenido, solo era para las pruebas de funcionamiento.

*formulario1.php:*

```
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <!--jquery.fileDownload.js -->
  <script src="http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/Scripts/jquery.fileDownload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h5>FORMULARIO 1</h5>
  <input type="button" id="btnDescargarNormal" value="Normal">
  <input type="button" id="btnDescargarError" value="Error">


  <!-- Sirve para indicar al usuario que se está realizando una descarga -->
  <div id="preparing-file-modal" title="Generando Reporte..." style="display: none;">
    Generando archivo, favor de esperar...
    <div class="ui-progressbar-value ui-corner-left ui-corner-right" style="width: 100%; height:22px; margin-top: 20px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="error-modal" title="Error" style="display: none;"></div>
  <!---->

  <script>
    (function() {

      var descargarArchivo = function(error) {
        var $preparingFileModal = $("#preparing-file-modal");

        $preparingFileModal.dialog({
          modal: true
        });

        var urlArchivo = 'devolverArchivo.php' + (error || '');

        $.fileDownload(urlArchivo, {
          successCallback: function(url) {
            //$preparingFileModal.dialog('close');
            location.href = 'formulario2.php';
          },
          failCallback: function(responseHtml, url) {
            $preparingFileModal.dialog('close');

            $("#error-modal").html(responseHtml).dialog({
              modal: true
            });
          }
        });
      }

      $('#btnDescargarNormal').on('click', function(e) {
        descargarArchivo(null);
      });

      $('#btnDescargarError').on('click', function(e) {
        descargarArchivo('?error=error');
      });

    })();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

*devolverArchivo.php:*

```
<?php
// Verificar parametro

if(isset($_GET["error"])){
    // Establecer error detectado
    header('Set-Cookie: fileDownload=false; path=/');
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    echo '<h5>No existen datos en la Base de Datos</h5>';
}
else{

    // Establecer el tipo de contenido, para el ejemplo yo considero una imagen
    header('Set-Cookie: fileDownload=true; path=/');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=60, must-revalidate');
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="archivoGenerado.png"');

    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);
    $blanco = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $gris = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
    $negro = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
    imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $blanco);
    $texto = '¡Bienvenido a SOes!';
    $fuente = 'arial.ttf';
    imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $gris, $fuente, $texto);
    imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $negro, $fuente, $texto);
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
}

?>
```

**Pruebas** Son capturas de pantalla del comportamiento cuando existe y no error.

*Sin Error*
[image: Prueba de repuesta sin error]

*Con Error*
[image: Prueba de repuesta con error]

*Espero haber solucionado tu problema.*

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte. Es lo mas cercano a lo que requeria. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Según veo, tienes algunos problemas conceptuales cuando intentas hacer la descarga. De acuerdo a tu codigo:

```
<p>Descargar PDF:
    <a href="verificar.view.php" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="imprime">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span> Descargar
    </a>
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $('#imprime').on('click', function () {
            var last_id = $(this).data().last_id;
            $.post( 'verifica.view.php', { last_id: last_id } );
        });
    });

    </script>
</p>
```

Realizas una petición AJAX (XHR, para utilizar los terminos correctos), mediante `POST` con el id del PDF generado. El problema, es que ese XHR solo es llamado en background y no controlas por ningún lado la respuesta de esta petición, es por ello que a pesar de generar el PDF de forma correcta, no puedes verlo.

Además, cuando dices:

> al momento de ejecutar me dice "No existen datos en la Base de Datos" siendo que si se registro y sigue activo el numero de registro hasta que cierro la ventana.

asumo que estás abriendo la URL en una nueva pestaña, pero según tu código, el id del registro se recupera mediante `POST` (`$ultimo_registro=isset($_POST['last_id']);`), es por ello que no funciona cuando abres la pestaña.

A modo de solución se me ocurre lo siguiente:

```
<p>Descargar PDF:
    <a href="verificar.view.php" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" target="_blank" id="imprime">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span> Descargar
    </a>
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $('#imprime').on('click', function () {
            var last_id = $(this).data().last_id;

            this.href = "verificar.view.php?last_id=" + last_id;
        });
    });

    </script>
</p>
```

y en el PHP de generacion de PDF, cambiar a:

```
$ultimo_registro=isset($_GET['last_id']);
```

Con esto lograrás tener URIs específicas para cada documento, las cuales puedes compartir.

---

Leyendo tu código, no estás sanitizando en ningún lugar tus inputs, lo que puede conllevar a [SQL Injections](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL). Para solucionar esto, te recomiendo utilizar [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepared-statements.php) de forma tal que el driver de la BD se preocupe de sanitizar tus inputs.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte y gran ayuda. Sin embargo estoy haciendo unas pruebas y al momento de presionar botón Descargar PDF, lo que hice fue primero ver que valores guardan las variables antes de generar el PDF y estoy observando que me manda a traer el primer registro. Es decir, la variable $ultimo_registro al momento de pasar a "verificar.view.php" ya no toma el valor del ultimo folio, sino que al hacer la consulta me toma el primer valor de la tabla. Es decir 1. ¿Porque será?

Comment: Pues resulta que con AJAX no me funciono. Asi que tuve que pasar sin necesidad de AJAX el valor de la variable para que me hiciera referencia al valor del folio y desde ahi generar la consulta. Tuve que quitar el isset de la variable $ultimo_registro y se solucionó mi problema. Gracias de todos modos por tus ideas.